# definition of functions that "weakly vanishes as $y\to\infty$" and find a proof of Theorem 9 in the article

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, definitions, fractional-calculus

I'm reading ["Extension problem and fractional operators: semigroups and wave equations"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.05159.pdf) by P.R. Stinga, i have two questions:

1. in Theorem 7 the author use the state "weakly vanishes as $y\to\infty$", what does it mean "weakly vanishes as $y\to\infty$"?
   \
2. Can someone help me to find, or give me, a proof of Theorem 9? I'm curious on how i can prove that: $ U\in H^1_a$, with the notations of article.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without having checked the details in the paper... I'd say that $U:\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ vanishes weakly as $y\to \infty$ if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} U(x,y)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x\to 0$ as $y\to \infty$ for all $\phi$ in some class of test functions (e.g. $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$).

Comment: How i can prove the uniqueness of $u$ in such class of weakly vanishes as $y\to\infty$?  Moreover, you have an idea for the second question?